# ItemRenderer Flex Values getting not rendered according to ArrayCollection Provider

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

i have a problem using the itemRenderer functionality. When using an ArrayCollection the visible Data in the DataGrid using the itemRenderer will be rendered just fine. But if i start scrolling the entries are repeating in the cells using the renderer. The cells are not filled with date according to the id. What mistake i'm doing here.

I read a lot of the explainations like:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html

here is the code for the set data function (itemRenderer is extending HBox):

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _data = value;

        if(data!=null)
        {
            var maxValue:Number = 0;
            var maxFontHeight:int = 18;

            for each(var term:ArrayCollection in _data.story)
            {
                if((term.getItemAt(1) as Number)>maxValue)
                    maxValue=term.getItemAt(1) as Number;
            }

            for each(var term:ArrayCollection in _data.story)
            {
                var FontHeight:int = Math.floor((term.getItemAt(1) as Number) * maxFontHeight / maxValue);

                var l:Label = new Label();
                l.text = term.getItemAt(0) as String;
                l.setStyle("fontWeight","normal");
                l.setStyle("fontFamily","Verdana");
                l.setStyle("paddingRight",0);
                l.setStyle("paddingLeft",0);
                l.setStyle("fontSize", FontHeight);
                l.setStyle("color", 0x000000);

                this.addChild(l);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't clearing down what's already there in the renderer before adding new stuff.

Try moving the construction of the label to createChildren, setting the text in set data (rather than constructing another label), and remembering to clear the text if the data is null.

There's a few more optimizations you could make such as checking the new data isn't the same as the current data before doing the work, for example.

Comment: I see the point in moving the creation of the labels. But does that work also if i need different amounts of labels within the different cells. sometimes there are more or less words to render. I understood the fact that there is only one instance of the itemRenderer but how can i than actually controll the rendering of each cell? I try to move the creation and get back with the results of that

Comment: Concatenate it all as a string, and set that single string on the label

Comment: No thats not the purpose couse the strings need differnt sizes like a tag cloud.

Comment: I got it to work with this.removeAllChildren(); before adding the labels to each cell. So your answer was helpful by stating that i always add new lables to the one instance of the itemRenderer.